# How to do in-place assignments in Rust?

Tags: rust

In C++, I can do in-place assignments that increment the variable `var` while printing it out to the screen:

```cpp
int var = 5;
std::cout << ( var += 1 ) << std::endl;
```

I am doing this because Rust does not have the in/decrement operators `++` & `--`. I tried it in Rust:

```
let mut counter = 0;
println!("{}", (counter += 1));
```

It is saying:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     println!("{}", (counter += 1));
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `()`
  |
  = note: `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assignment operators in Rust don't evaluate to the assigned value; they evaluate to `()`. Therefore, you need to read the variable after the assignment to obtain the new value. You can do this with a block, since blocks are also expressions.

```
let mut counter = 0;
println!("{}", { counter += 1; counter });
```

If you're going to do this often, consider defining a macro:

```
macro_rules! inc {
    ($e:expr) => {
        { $e += 1; $e }
    }
}

let mut counter = 0;
println!("{}", inc!(counter));
```

Answer (score 8):

The shortest solution is to return the value:

```
let mut counter = 0;
println!("{}", {counter += 1; counter});
```

But honestly, I would say that this isn't idiomatic Rust, and you might as well just write it on another line:

```
let mut counter = 0;
counter += 1;
println!("{}", counter);
```

---

The longer answer is that you cannot get the value of the assignment. The trait for [`AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) is defined as

```
pub trait AddAssign<Rhs = Self> {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, Rhs);
}
```

Notably, there is no value returned from the method. Rust does not have a useful value for the result of an assignment because *there isn't one*, in general. Ownership semantics make it complicated to figure out what the "return value" of something like `let x = String::new();` should be. If it were a `String`, then what would have happened to the ownership held by `x`?

Since all expressions return *some* type, assignments return the empty tuple (`()`), also known as the *unit type*.

In *this* case, the value is an integer, which implements the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait. That means that you can trivially return a copy from the block.

The same solution would "work" for a `String`, until you tried to use it afterwards:

```
let mut string = String::new();
println!("{}", {string += "a"; string});
println!("{}", string); // use of moved value: `string`
```

Which could be fixed by returning a reference:

```
println!("{}", {string += "a"; &string});
```

But at this point, there's not really any "saving" to be done.