# Why does an if without an else always result in () as the value?

Tags: rust

From this [tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/if.html):

> An if without an else always results in () as the value.

Why does Rust impose this restriction and doesn't let an `if` without an `else` return other values, like this:

```
let y = if x == 5 { 10 };
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For your example, the right question is: “What would the value of `y` be if `x` is not 5?”. What would happen here?

```
let x = 3;
let y = if x == 5 { 10 };
println!("{}", y);  // what?!
```

You could think that the if-without-else-expression could return an `Option<_>`, but...

1. this would mean that the core language depends on yet another library item (those are then called *lang items*) which everyone tries to avoid
2. you don't run into this situation too often
3. you can get the same behavior by adding only a little bit of code (`Some()` & `else { None }`)

---

In Rust, nearly everything is an expression (with the exception of `let`-bindings and expressions ending with a semicolon, so called *expression statements*). And there are a few examples of expressions always returning `()`, because nothing else makes sense. These include (compound-)assignments ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058897/2408867)), loops and if-without-else.