# Conditionally assigning to a variable using `if`

Tags: if-statement, rust, expression

I have a struct of arguments and then try to do some basic logic on the output and assign the argument value to a variable upon certain conditions:

```
struct Args {
    name: String,
    from: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args {
        name: "Jane".to_string(),
        from: "Jane Doe <jane@example.com>".to_string(),
    };
    let default_username: String = "Sendmail Wrapper".to_owned();

    let username = if args.name != default_username {
        args.name.clone();
    };
    let username = if (args.name == default_username) && (args.from != default_username) {
        args.from.clone();
    };
    println!("{}",username);
}
```

When running the code above I get and error from Rust:

```
error[E0277]: `()` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/main.rs:73:19
   |
73 |     println!("{}",username);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^ `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `println` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

If I use `println!("{:?}",username);` or `println!("{:#?}",username);` I simply get `()` printed.

How do I assign the struct variables to the username variable?

Comment: This isn't related to `clap` at all, as you could condense this to the following [mre]: `println!("{}", if true { ""; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably expected `username` to be of type `String`, but the problem lies in this:

```
let username = if args.name != default_username {
    args.name.clone();
};
```

Similarly, you then have this block, which essentially suffers from the same problem:

```
let username = if (args.name == default_username) && (args.from != default_username) {
    args.from.clone();
};
```

The compiler needs something more deterministic. In other words, you need to have and `else` block as well. Something like this:

```
let username = if <condition> {
    args.name.clone()
} else {
    args.from.clone()
}
```

Note that in that variant we are not only having an `else` block, which covers all possible cases, but the blocks don't have a `;` at the end.

---

Why is it important not to have semicolons? Let's find out with this simple program:

```
fn main() {
    let t = 5;
    let username = if t > 6 {
        "foo";
    } else {
        "bar";
    };
    username.asdf();
}
```

And let's take a look at the compiler error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `asdf` found for unit type `()` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |         username.asdf();
  |                  ^^^^ method not found in `()`
```

Now let's try the same thing without the semicolons:

```
fn main() {
    let t = 5;
    let username = if t > 6 {
        "foo"
    } else {
        "bar"
    };
    username.asdf();
}
```

The compiler error is slightly different this time:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `asdf` found for reference `&str` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:18
  |
9 |         username.asdf();
  |                  ^^^^ method not found in `&str`
```

As we can see, in the second example the compiler says `username` is of type `&str` (what we would have expected, right?). However, in the previous example (with the semicolons), the compiler says `username` is of type `()` (a tuple with zero elements, which in Rust is something like the `void` type in languages like C, C++, Java, C#, etc.).

The reason for this behavior is that we are using an `if/else` block as an *expression* and in Rust, when the last line in a block has no `;` at the end, that essentially means `return the_expression;`.

Again, let me explain the above with an example. When you have this block:

```
{
    foo
}
```

Rust interprets that as:

```
{
    return foo;
}
```

But when you have this block:

```
{
    foo;
}
```

Rust interprets it as something like this:

```
{
    foo;
    return ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! For future people who are confused like I was this additional reading helped me understand this answer to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43335193/why-does-an-if-without-an-else-always-result-in-as-the-value

Comment: Nitpick - these `return`s are not to be taken literally, since taken literally they would mean "return from the current _function_" and not "...from the current _block_". That's only a single case when they are the same.